# Best way of loading content that should appear on every page

Tags: php, html, iframe, dynamic

Until now, I've been using the `<iframe>` tag to load things like headers/footers/navbars into my webpage. These cause so much hassle though and as I'm about to start building a new site I thought I'd get it sorted now.

I was thinking of having all the html code in a php file and just loading it in dynamically.. Ideally I'd like the code to become a part of the page. So it appears inline. But I also want to be able to edit one single file if I need to change one bit rather than editing the same file 100 times.

`<iframe>`'s did this well until recently and I don't want to use workarounds to solve my problems. Could someone please post some code I could adapt or post a link to something that tells me how to do this? Cheers

Comment: You could use a templating engine (e.g. http://www.smarty.net/). They usually offer ways to reuse page fragments.

Comment: In case your PHP knowledge is limited, you might better look into content management systems like Joomla, WordPress and Drupal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use PHP's `include()` function to include elements like headers and footers in your pages.

So:

```
include('header.php');
```

. . . will look for a file called header.php in the same directory and include it in your page.  Then you just need to write this at the top of your pages.

That said, this isn't really a very good way to go about designing your site.  How about looking for a [content management system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system), that allows you to keep the design and content of your site separate?

Comment: Sounds about right for what I want to do. Is this bad practise because of performance or compatibility (It's usually one of them). 

Also. If I were to 'include' an HTML document, will it just render the code on the original page?

Comment: Yes. . . the include function will just copy and paste the contents of the selected file - this could be PHP or HTML.

Comment: It is just quite a lot of effort to produce each page of your site in this way.  Working with a CMS like Wordpress or Drupal will mean you can create pages and make changes to your design in seconds not minutes.  Most CMS products come with lots of other features that make managing a site easier.

Comment: I'm building it for someone who wants specific CMS-like features and I'm not going to start editing a complicated CMS like opencart. I'm starting a PHP internet course thing today I just needed this one little bit for a workaround :)

Comment: Out of interest.. How bad practise is it to use `<iframe>`'s as I currently am?

Comment: The iframe method is not great - as you're basically loading 3 pages instead of one on the user's browser.  The include method is better because the page is built on the server and then sent complete to the user.

Comment: If you're building the site for someone else who doesn't have any PHP/HTML skills will they be able to create new pages or update the site easily - or are they going to need to come back to you for help?  A CMS would allow your client to create/update content without the need for any specific coding knowledge.  Once you've done this PHP course, install a copy of Wordpress somewhere and have a play with it.  It will save you loads of time and hassle once you've learned the basics of how to use it!

Answer (score 2):

Are PHP includes what you're looking for ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php